# How to resize Ionic main contents when toggling a subheader using ngIf

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to toggle an Ionic sub header on/off using an `ngIf` as in the following

```
<div class="bar bar-subheader" ng-if=showSubheader>
    <h2 class="title">Sub Header</h2>        
 </div>

 <ion-content class="has-subheader">
    <div data-ng-include="'app/main/main.html'"></div>
 </ion-content>
```

And setting the $scope.showSubheader to true / false. The sub menu shows/hide fine, but the main content does not resize when the sub header is toggled.

I have tried adding an adding/removing the class `has-subheader` in the code behind, and calling `$scope.apply()`, but nothing seems to "refresh" the main contents height. If I have the `class="has-subheader"` there initially, then there is always a space for the subheader, visible or not, if I don't have it there, then the subheader covers the top of the main contents.

I had trouble getting a plunk to show the Ionic headers, so haven't made one at this stage (hoping this description will be enough)

Also, I am using this inside of an Ionic [splitview](http://blog.ionic.io/splitview-has-landed)...

```
<ion-side-menus>
<ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <button class="button button-icon ion-navicon" ng-click="vm.toggleLeft()" ng-hide="$exposeAside.active"></button>
        <h1 style="text-align: left" class="title">Title</h1>            
    </ion-header-bar>

    <div class="bar bar-subheader" ng-if=showSubheader>
     <h2 class="title">Sub Header</h2>        
   </div>

    <ion-content id="maincontent" class="padding has-subheader">
        <div data-ng-include="'app/main/main.html'"></div>
    </ion-content>

  <ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar-balanced"></ion-footer-bar>
</ion-side-menu-content>

<ion-side-menu width={{vm.menuwidth}} expose-aside-when={{vm.exposewhen}}>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-royal">
        <h1 style="text-align: left" class="title">Options</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        <div data-ng-include="'app/options/options.html'"></div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

Does anyone know a way around this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be this can be one direction..!

```
 <div ng-class="{' bar bar-subheader':(showSubheader)}" >
    <h2 class="title">Sub Header</h2>
 </div>
```

similarly, try for `has-subheader` class in `<ion-content>`

Comment: Great, thankyou very much, this does want I am after!

Answer (score 0):

Call `$ionicScrollDelegate.resize()` when you add/remove the subheader.

[Documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/)

Comment: thanks for that. For some reason it didn't seem to work for me, the height of the content seems to stay fixed according to whether or not it has the class `has-subheader`. Maybe it is because I am using a [splitview](http://blog.ionic.io/splitview-has-landed)? I may have to try and get an online sample working

Comment: I have added some more to the question info re the markup I am using.